# Kendo UI Grid edit on row click instead of edit button click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Does anyone know of a way to trigger the editing of a row just by clicking the row?

I would like to see the same functionality that I see when I click an edit command button, but triggered by selecting the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your change event for your grid:

```
myGrid.setOptions({
            editable: {
                mode: "inline"
            },
            change: function(){
                  this.editRow(this.select());
            }
});
```

Comment: When I use this code (and I've tried a similar approach previously), I get the row to go into edit mode; however, I can't do much with it at that point, because everything I click on in the row fires the event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just had need for a solution and this is what worked for me. I wanted to use double-click, but the click event should also work.

```
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
$('#grid .k-grid-content table').on(
  'dblclick',
  'tr',
  function () { grid.editRow($(this)); }
);
```

The selector (`"#grid .k-grid-content table"`) works for my current configuration (mainly I have virtual scrolling turned on) and so may need to be adjusted for your specific situation.